# How can I get my map to be fluid (shrink and grow with the viewport size)?

Tags: html, css, google-maps, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I am creating a google map site/app that shows "the lower 48" (contiguous United States). On a largish screen, it looks as I want it to:

[image]

...but when I reduce the viewport / viewing area (by mashing the resize button (or whatever it's called) in the NE corner of the screen), the map doesn't redraw smaller, as I want it to, but just shows the map at the same size and thus mostly hidden:

[image]

The google map area is defined in HTML this way:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

CSS I'm using that may be pertinent:

```
html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
}

#map {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/5AEEV/117/

Comment: No, what I'm looking for (and I'm not even sure it's a good idea, because on a phone, the map would be so small you would need a magnifying glass to see details) is a fluid layout, where the map would take up the entire layout (resize). IOW, one would see the entire USA (lower 48) map - nothing more, nothing less - no matter how large or small the screen/viewport is. Again, though, I'm not even sure it's a good idea; the best all in all may be the way it already works.